# Asymptotics of sum of binomials

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

How can you compute the asymptotics of

$$S=n  + m - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}\;?$$

We have that $n \geq m$ and $n,m \geq 1$.

A simple application of Stirling's approximation gives

$$S \approx T =  n + m - \frac{n^{3/2-m}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k)^{m-1/2}}{k^{3/2}}$$

A more accurate approximation is given by

$$n+m- \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{12 n}\right) n }{\sqrt{2 \pi }} \sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{ (1-\frac{k}{n})^{m-\frac{1}{2}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{12 k}\right) k^{3/2} \left(1+\frac{1}{12 (n-k)}\right) }$$

Via an indirect and handy wavy argument, my <strike>guess is</strike> guess for constant $m$ is that the answer is

$$S \sim \sqrt{2n} \frac{\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})}{(m-1)!}$$

**Update.**  When $m$ grows almost as quickly as $n$ I think my guess is an underestimate.  For example when $n=m$ it seems numerically that $S \sim 1.841 n$ and in fact if $n=m$ then it is suggested that $S \sim n\left(2-\left( -W\left(-\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^2}\right)\right)\right)$ (see [Is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} (n-k)^{2n-k} \binom{n}{k} \sim\frac{n^{2n}}{2\pi} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363663/is-sum-k-1n-kk-1-n-k2n-k-binomnk-sim-fracn2n2-pi)).

**Update 2.**  When $m=1$ then $S$ is precisely the average number of people required to find a pair with the same birthday.  This is solved at the wikipedia entry for the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people) and so $S \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$ (which equals  my guess above).  I would however ideally like to find the asymptotics in terms of $m$ and $n$ without assuming that $m$ is fixed.

**Update 3.**  For the $m=1$ case we can prove that the correct asymptotics is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$ in two ways.

- We will first show the result using the following identity.

$$n  + 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(n-k)^{n+1-k}}{n^{n+1-1}}=1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} = 1+Q(n)$$

The numerator of the sum on the left is $n^{n+1}-Q(n)n^n$ (Q(n) is called Ramanujan's function by Knuth) according to [A219706](http://oeis.org/A219706) and [A063169](http://oeis.org/A063169).  This immediately gives the identity.

We also know that $Q(n) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$ from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people) (is there a better reference?).

- The second proof follows from the amazing [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365440/estimate-sum-k-1n-kk-1-binomnk-n-kn1-k) of GEdgar where he shows that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k+1} =
 n^n\Bigg( n
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} n^{1/2} + \frac{1}{3}
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{24} n^{-1/2}
 +\frac{4}{135}n^{-1}
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{576}n^{-3/2}
 +O\left(n^{-2}\right)\Bigg)
$$

Comment: How did you get this answer?

Comment: check your question for typos, because the answer you've come up with is pretty far off if the question is as stated.

Comment: What is the relative size of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Numerics for fixed $m$ suggest that your conjectured constant is not accurate. For $m=1$ the actual values of $S/\sqrt{2n}$ quickly descend below $1$ and seem smoothly decreasing as $n$ increases. For fixed $m\ge2$, the value of $S/\sqrt{2n}$ is also smoothly decreasing as $n$ increases, but they don't seem like they will get down to $\Gamma((m+1)/2)/\Gamma(m)$.

Comment: What is the context? Do you have any empirical evidence for your claim?

Comment: @GregMartin There was another typo (fixed). The numerator was meant to be $\Gamma(m+1/2)$

Comment: Have you tried using the following?

$$ n^n = \dfrac{n! e^{n-\lambda_n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$

where $\frac{1}{12n+1} \lt \lambda_n \lt \frac{1}{12n}$

Comment: @Aryabhata  Not successfully.  Do you see a way to get the answer that way?

Comment: @motl737: For $m=1/2$ at least, it might work (you might also have to use Euler-McLaurin Summation formula). But,I seem to get something different from what you have, but it is a bit complicated and error-prone, so I need to recheck. I might post it sometime today, if I confirm the correctness.

Comment: Here is another idea: The power series for $\dfrac{1}{1+W(-z)} -1$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^n z^n}{n!}$ (for $|z| \lt 1/e$). Taking the square gives you coefficients similar to what you want (at least the binomial summation part). So you need to estimate the $n^{th}$ derivative of that. See J.M.'s answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/352204/1102 (and the question itself is closely related).

Comment: Is the $-$ in $S$ correct? Because then $S$ would be negative, and certainly smaller than your given large formula in $n$ and $m$.

Comment: @TMM $S$ can't be negative far as I know.  What do you mean? I just tested it by computer as well.

Comment: Are you saying the sum is always less than $n + m$?

Comment: @TMM Yes. I believe so. At least for $n \geq m$.

Comment: For fixed $m$ positive integer we do have $S \sim \sqrt{2n} \frac{\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})}{(m-1)!}$ from the same method as in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/365972/442

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first answer showed that small $k$ play a major role in the sum. Since Stirling is an asymptotic approximation, the approximation for small $k$ was not be good enough. My second answer showed that Stirling should be used for $n!$ and $(n-k)!$ since they will be large. My third approach overvalued $\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}$. This approach uses the series for the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) given in $(9)$ and approximations given in $(10)$.
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^nk^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+O\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\right)\frac{n^{n+1/2}}{(n-k)^{n-k+1/2}}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+O\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\right)\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
If we let $\alpha=\dfrac{m-1/2}{n}$, then $\left(1-\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\le e^{-k\alpha}$. Therefore, using the approximation for $\mathrm{W}'(x)$ given in $(10)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}
&\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^{k(1+\alpha)}}\\
&=\frac1n\mathrm{W}'(-e^{-1-\alpha})\\
&\le\frac1n\frac{e^2}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\\
&=\frac{e^2}{\sqrt{(2m-1)n}}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the big-O term in $(11)$ is insignificant. Using the series for $\mathrm{W}(x)$ from $(9)$ and remembering that $\mathrm{W}(-1/e)=-1$
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\\
&-n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\\
&=n-n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\\
&-n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Now we *can* use Stirling to approximate $\dfrac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}=\dfrac{k^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}                                                              +O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)$.

First, we evaluate the tail from the first sum in $(13)$
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}
&=n\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left(\frac{k^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$
Next, the error term in the second sum in $(13)$
$$
\begin{align}
&n\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-5/2}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\\
&\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty k^{-3/2}\right) \,\sup_k\left\{\frac{n}{k}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\right\}\\[6pt]
&\le\zeta(3/2)(m-1/2)\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Finally, the main term in the second sum in $(13)$ is a Riemann Sum in disguise
$$
\begin{align}
&n\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^{-3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\\
&=\frac{n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{-3/2}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}\right)\frac1n\\
&\sim\frac{n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^1x^{-3/2}\left(1-(1-x)^{m-1/2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(u)-\cos^{2m}(u)}{\sin^2(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(-1+\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}\cos^k(u)\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+\cos(u)}\\
&=\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(-\frac1{1+\cos(u)}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\cos^{2k}(u)\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac{2n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k}(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac{2n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{2\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac\pi2\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\\
&=-\frac{2n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{\pi\,n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{2m}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}\tag{16}
\end{align}
$$
The last step uses the identity $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac1{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{2m}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}$.

> Putting together $(11)-(14)$ yields
>   $$
> n+m-\sum_{k=1}^nk^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{m}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}+O(m-1/2)\tag{17}
> $$
>   Using Stirling to approximate $\dfrac1{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}\sim\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi m}}$, $(17)$ gives, for large $m$,
>   $$
> n+m-\sum_{k=1}^nk^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}
> \sim\sqrt{2mn}\tag{18}
> $$
>   as my earlier answers did.

---

**Further Considerations**

The case where $m=\alpha n$, for some constant $\alpha$, cannot be handled by $(17)$ since the error term is $O(m)=O(\alpha n)$ and that would be similar in size to $\sqrt{2mn}=\sqrt{2\alpha}n$. To handle this case, we start with the sum at the beginning of $(13)$
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^k}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}
&\sim n\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^{k(1+\alpha)}}\\
&=-n\mathrm{W}(-e^{-1-\alpha})
\end{align}
$$

> Thus,
>   $$
> n+m-\sum_{k=1}^nk^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-k)^{n+m-k}}{n^{n+m-1}}
> \sim n(1+\alpha+\mathrm{W}(-e^{-1-\alpha}))\tag{19}
> $$
>   For $m=n$, where $\alpha=1$, this is $n\left(2+\mathrm{W}(-e^{-2})\right)=n\,1.84140566043696063785$

---

**Derivation of the series for $\mathrm{W}(x)$**

Here is an identity we will use later
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}k^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k-1}\binom{n-k-1}{j}n^{j}(-1)^{n-k-j-1}k^{n-k-j-1}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}n^{j}(-1)^{n-j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-j-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-k-1}{j}k^{n-j-2}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}n^{j}(-1)^{n-j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-k-1}{j}k^{n-j-2}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}n^{j}(-1)^{n-j-1}\binom{n-1}{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}\binom{-1}{j}n^{n-j-2}\tag{4}\\
&=(n-1)n^{n-2}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$: binomial theorem

$(2)$: change order of summation

$(3)$: add terms where $\binom{n-k-1}{j}=0$

$(4)$: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^k\binom{n-k-1}{j}k^{n-j-2}=0$ since $\binom{n-k-1}{j}k^{n-j-2}$ is a degree $n-2$ polynomial in $k$

$(5)$: each term in the sum was $n^{n-2}$

---

Taking the log-derivative of $we^w=x$ gives $\frac{w'}{w}+w'=\frac1x$ which yields the equation
$$
w=w'(1+w)x\tag{6}
$$
from which we will derive a recursion for the power series for $\mathrm{W}(x)$. Suppose that
$$
\mathrm{W}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n\tag{7}
$$
Using $we^w=x$ and equations $(6)$ and $(7)$, we get that $a_k$ satisfy $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{n!}
&=n\frac{a_n}{n!}
+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\frac{a_k}{k!}\frac{a_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
-(n-1)\,a_n
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}k\,a_ka_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}n\,a_ka_{n-k}\\
a_n
&=-\frac{n}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a_ka_{n-k}\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Putting together $(5)$ and $(8)$, we get that
$$
\mathrm{W}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n\tag{9}
$$

---

**Behavior of $\mathrm{W}(x)$ for $x\sim-1/e$**

For $\alpha$ near $0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{W}\left(-e^{-1-\alpha}\right)
&\doteq-1+\sqrt{2\alpha}-\frac13\sqrt{2\alpha}^2+\frac7{36}\sqrt{2\alpha}^3\\ 
\mathrm{W}'\left(-e^{-1-\alpha}\right)
&\doteq\frac{e^{1+\alpha}}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\left(1-\frac23\sqrt{2\alpha}-\frac1{12}\sqrt{2\alpha}^2\right)\\
\mathrm{W}''\left(-e^{-1-\alpha}\right)
&\doteq-\frac{e^{2+2\alpha}}{\sqrt{2\alpha}^3}\left(1-\frac{19}{12}\sqrt{2\alpha}^2\right)
\end{align}\tag{10}
$$

Comment: +1. I was getting something similar, but didn't trust my calculations...

Comment: @robjohn  I don't think this can be right. For $m=1$, $S$ is precisely the average number of people required to find a pair with the same birthday and hence $S \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$.  I think my old guess might be correct for fixed $m$.

Comment: I was also hoping to find the asymptotics for $m$ growing with $n$ as well.

Comment: @motl737: I gave the asymptotic behavior for $\frac mn\sim\alpha$. I don't know if there is a reasonable formula for general $m$ and $n$. I have not found a closed form for
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-k\alpha}}{k^{3/2}}
$$
but the value for $\alpha=0$ is $\zeta(3/2)$. Mathematica defines this function as $\mathsf{PolyLog[3/2,Exp[-}\alpha\mathsf{]]}$.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry if I am missing something simple but my first concern is that for $m=1$ and $n$ going to infinity (so $\alpha \rightarrow 0$) your answer doesn't seem right (maybe it is Stirling's approximation that is causing the problem).  With respect to the sum, you can compute the integral to infinity if that helps at all.

Comment: So for small $m$ and large $n$, you get $S = n + m - \sum [\ldots] \to n + m - (1.04\ldots)n < 0$?

Comment: @TMM The problem is Stirling's approximation which is too crude I think.  The constant should be below $1$.

Comment: @motl737: my answer shows that small $k$ play a major role in the sum. Since Stirling is an asymptotic approximation, the approximation for small $k$ may not be good enough. I am reworking my answer and coming across some interesting identities.

Comment: @robjohn: That is why I was trying to consider the $\lambda_n$ term in the approximation (see my comments on the question), and I believe that is valid for all $n$. Perhaps you could work that in?

Comment: @Aryabhata: I just noticed your comment. I may have saved some time if I had noticed it earlier, but I have just finished computing
$$
W(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-k)^{k-1}}{k!}x^k
$$
I am almost finished with my updated answer.

Comment: @Aryabhata: it took a bit longer to finish. Done now, and it is close to what motl737 thought it would be $\sqrt{2mn}$.

Comment: For $n=100,m=1$ my approximation is within $0.2$ of the actual answer.

Comment: @robjohn: Thanks! It will take quite some time to go through the whole thing :-)

Comment: @robjohn That's really impressive! Thank you.  One thing I didn't understand quite understand. If $m = n/100$ say then $a =1/100$.  Does your approximation still hold in this case?

Comment: @motl737: it worked or $n=100,m=1$. Did you have some particular values you were concerned about?

Comment: @robjohn I hope this isn't too fussy but does your result give the correct asymptotics for the case $m=1$.  You get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S/\sqrt{n} = \frac{7}{4\sqrt{2}}$ I think even including your error term. Unless I made a silly mistake. It should be $ S/\sqrt{n} \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: @robjohn I have checked and $S \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$ when $m=1$ (assuming you believe oeis). See my question at  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128014/elementary-proof-for-identity-involving-sums-of-binomials .

Comment: @robjohn I think the problem is in the claim $n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{k-\alpha k^2}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)
\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^{k(1+\alpha)}}
=-n\mathrm{W}\left(-e^{-1-\alpha}\right)
+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\Big((1-\alpha)k-\alpha k(k-1)\Big)
\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!\,e^{k(1+\alpha)}}
+O\left(\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: @motl737: I am aware that $\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^{m-1/2}$ needs a different approach for small $m$, and I am working on that. However, $\alpha$ *is* constant when $m$ grows with $n$ (which was one of mentioned at one point).

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! If $m/n$ is a constant that is an interesting case you are right. $m$ could grow like $n^c$ as well where $0< c< 1$.

Comment: @motl737: I think the current answer is good.

Comment: Thanks again!  Your new result holds for constant $m$ right? It isn't true for $m=n$ for example.

Comment: Since the error term is $O(m)$, the result holds for $m=n$, but is meaningless. To be meaningful, we would want $m/n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks! I suppose your previous method works when $m/n$ is a constant in any case.

Comment: @motl737: I just verified for my comment to GEdgar that your guess matches my answer. That is,
$$
\sqrt{2n}\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac12\right)}{(m-1)!}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{m}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}
$$

Comment: That's really great. Thank you again. So something amazing happens between $m=n^{1-\epsilon}$ and $m=n$ where the asymptotic prefactor jumps from $\sqrt{2}$ to roughly $1.841$.  I wonder how that happens.

Comment: "I suppose your previous method works when $m/n$ is a constant". I wouldn't trust my previous answers. I believe that this answer fixes problems in my previous attempts.

Comment: @motl737: "So something amazing happens between $m=n^{1-\epsilon}$ and $m=n$ where the asymptotic prefactor jumps from $\sqrt2$ to roughly $1.841$." It might be useful to note that as $n\to\infty$, $n^{1-\epsilon}/n\to0$. That is, most of $n$ is above $n^{1-\epsilon}$

Comment: @motl737: Check out the Further Considerations above.

Answer (score 2):

Computation for constant $m$ positive integer.
This uses the same method as in [Estimate $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} (n-k)^{n+1-k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365440/) ,
further explanation is there.

Write
\begin{equation*}
 u_{-1}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} z^n
\tag{1}\end{equation*}
Then the unique singularity nearest to the origin is at $z=e^{-1}$,
and we have an expansion there:
\begin{equation*}
 u_{-1}(z) = 1 - \sqrt{2}(1-ez)^{1/2}+\frac{2}{3}(1-ez)
 +O\left((1-ez)^{3/2}\right)
\tag{2}\end{equation*}
as $z \to e^{-1}$ from the left.
Define recursively $u_m(z) = z u_{m-1}'(z)$ for $m = 0,1,2,\dots$.
Then we have
\begin{equation*}
 u_m(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{n+m}}{n!}z^n
\tag{3}\end{equation*}
by induction.  To expand these at $e^{-1}$ we will also need
the expansion of $z$:
\begin{equation*}
 z = e^{-1} - e^{-1}(1-ez) = e^{-1} +O\left((1-ez)^1\right)
\tag{4}\end{equation*}
Now differentiate (2) and multiply by (4) to get
\begin{align*}
 u_0(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-ez)^{-1/2}-\frac{2}{3}
 +O\left((1-ez)^{1/2}\right)
\tag{5}\end{align*}
Differentiate this and multiply by (4) to get
\begin{align*}
 u_1(z) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} (1-ez)^{-3/2}
 +O\left((1-ez)^{-1/2}\right)
 \\ &= 
 \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} (1-ez)^{-3/2}
 +O\left((1-ez)^{-1/2}\right)
\end{align*}
Continuing, by induction we get
\begin{equation*}
 u_m(z) = \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(1-ez)^{-m-1/2}
 +O\left((1-ez)^{-m+1/2}\right)
\tag{6}\end{equation*}
for $m \ge 1$.

Now fix positive integer $m$.  (The extra term $-2/3$ in (5) 
mean that the formula for $m=0$ is different, but can also be done
by this method.)
Multiply (1) and (3) to get
\begin{equation*}
 h(z) := u_{-1}(z)u_m(z)
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n!}
 \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}\,
 \frac{(n-k)^{n-k+m}}{(n-k)!}\right)z^n
 =:\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n
\end{equation*}
Multiply (2) and (6) to get
$$
 h(z) = \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(1-ez)^{-m-1/2}
 -\frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}(1-ez)^{-m}
 +O\left((1-ez)^{-m+1/2}\right)
$$
as $z \to e^{-1}$ from the left.  So by the Szegö method, we get
an asymptotic series
\begin{align*}
 c_n &\approx e^n\left[
 \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\binom{n+m-1/2}{n}
 -\frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\binom{n+m-1}{n}+\dots
 \right]
 \\
 c_n &= e^n\Bigg[
 \frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(
 \frac{1}{\Gamma(m+1/2)}n^{m-1/2}+O(n^{m-3/2})\right)
 \\ &\qquad\qquad
 -\frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(
 \frac{1}{(m-1)!}n^{m-1} +O\left(n^{m-2}\right)
 \right) +O\left(n^{m-3/2}\right)
 \Bigg]
 \\ &=
 e^n\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}n^{m-1/2}
 -\frac{\Gamma(m+1/2)}{(m-1)!\sqrt{\pi}}n^{m-1}+O\left(n^{m-3/2}\right)\right]
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$.

Multiply by Stirling's formula,
$$
 n! = e^{-n}n^n\sqrt{2\pi}\left(
 n^{1/2}+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\right)
$$
to get
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} \frac{k^{k-1} 
 (n-k)^{n-k+m}}{n^{n+m-1}} = c_n\frac{n!}{n^{n+m-1}}
% \\ &\qquad
 = n - \frac{\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma(m+1/2)}{(m-1)!}\,n^{1/2} + O\left(1\right)
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
 S &=
 n+m-\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} \frac{k^{k-1} 
 (n-k)^{n-k+m}}{n^{n+m-1}}
 \\  &=
 n+O\left(1\right)
 -n + \frac{\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma(m+1/2)}{(m-1)!}\,n^{1/2} 
 + O\left(1\right)
 \\
 &=
 \frac{\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma(m+1/2)}{(m-1)!}\,n^{1/2} 
 + O\left(1\right)
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$, since $m$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks! Does this completely fail when $m$ grows with $n$ or does it depend on how it grows with $n$?  For example, what if we assume that $m/n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to  $\infty$?

Comment: As far as I can see, this does not work at all for $n=m$ as in one of your other questions.  Nor in any case when $m$ increases with $n$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I just verified that our answers agree. That is,
$$
\frac{\sqrt2\,\Gamma(m+1/2)}{(m-1)!}n^{1/2}=\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{m}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m}
$$

Comment: @robjohn Does this mean that GEdgar's answer (and my guess) is in fact right asymptotically even for $m=n^{1-\epsilon}$ even though GEdgar's proof technique doesn't prove it?

Comment: @motl737: it would seem so, since the expressions are equal.