# Scaling of a sum with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I am interested in how the sum
\begin{equation}
f(N)\equiv\frac 1{(N-1)!}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}\binom{2n+N}{2n-1}
\end{equation}
scales for large $N$. So far, I tried to expand the binomial into factorials and to use Stirling's approximation with the terms involving $N$; this, however, could not help in finding a simple scaling law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough approach.  The two largest summands are the last, ${5N-2 \choose 2N-1}$ and ${5N-4 \choose 2N-2}$  Their ratio is $\frac{(5N-2)!(2N-2)!(3N-2)!}{(5N-4)!(3N-1)!(2N-1)!}=\frac{(5N-2)(5N-3)}{(3N-1)(2N-1)}\approx \frac {25}6$.  That ratio between terms will not change quickly, so we can imagine it being a geometric series with that ratio.  The sum will then be $1+\frac 6{19}$ times the largest term, which we can expand by Stirling
$$f(N) \approx \frac {25}{19}\frac{(5N-2)!}{(3N-1)!(2N-1)!}\\
\approx \frac {25}{19}\frac{(5N-2)^{5N-2}}{(3N-1)^{3N-1}(2N-1)^{2N-1}}\sqrt{\frac{5N-2}{2\pi (3N-1)(2N-1)}}\\
\approx \frac {25}{19}\left(\frac {5^5}{3^32^2}\right)^N\frac6{5^2}\sqrt{\frac{5}{12\pi N}}$$
where the exponential terms cancel.  The term in parentheses is about $28.9$ so this gives an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation. Do you infer the scaling as a geometric series from the fact that the ratio of the largest terms is independent on N, hence they behave as $x^N$?

Comment: It is an approximation because I ignored the constants.  If $N \gg 3$ it will be accurate for a while.  As the terms decrease so rapidly, only the first few will be dominant in the sum.

Comment: @Graz It can be shown in [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2773889) that the approximation by a geometric series in fact gives the correct leading term. Fixing some typos, we have
$$(N - 1)! \hspace {1.5px} f(N) \sim
\frac {16} 9 \left( \frac {5^5} {2^8} \right)^{\! N} \sqrt {\frac {10} {\pi N}},
\quad N \to \infty.$$

Comment: @Maxim:  I don't see the typos you claim.  The $3$ s in the denominator come from the $(3N-1)^{3N-1}$ term, the $\frac 6{25}$ from the $-2$ and $-1$s on the exponents.

Comment: The last term in the sum is $\binom {5 N - 2} {4 N - 3}$.

Comment: @Maxim:  But that doesn't matter.  I just multiplied the first term in the sum by $\frac {25}{19}$ to cover the contribution of all the remaining terms.