# Estimate $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} (n-k)^{n+1-k}$

Tags: asymptotics

> I'm interested in estimating
>
> $$X_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1} (n-k)^{n+1-k}$$
>
> up to and including terms of order $n^n$; that is, I want $f_n$ in
>   $X_n=f_n+o\left(n^n\right)$.

The following identity looks very similar but I am not sure how to use it.
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(k-1)^k(n-k+1)^{n-k-1}= n^n$$

I think the answer should be

$$f_n=\frac{n^n}{2} \left(2+2n-\sqrt{2 \pi n}\right)\;.$$

The question arises from [Asymptotics of sum of binomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361452/asymptotics-of-sum-of-binomials) .

The reason why I am interested is to give the asymptotics of

$$Y=n  + 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(n-k)^{n+1-k}}{n^{n}}$$

I believe  that $Y$ equals $1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$.  (Separate [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128014/how-to-prove-n-1-sum-k1n-kk-1-binomnk-fracn-kn1-kn) posted for this identity.)

**Update.** $X_n$ is [oeis A219706](http://oeis.org/A219706).

Comment: Change index in the identity you are citing from $k$ to $m+1$ so $k-1 \to m$ and convert $\binom{n,m+1}$ to $\binom{n,m}$ by multiplying by the right things, that could clear hings up considerably

Comment: What does "*the* asymptotics" and "*the* answer" refer to here? If your asymptotic result is correct, then $X\sim n^{n+1}$ is also a correct answer.

Comment: @joriki Oh you are right. Hmm.. I need those lower order terms too. Can you help me rephrase it?

Comment: @motl737: I tried -- is this what you meant?

Comment: @joriki Yes, thanks! I also added the full background at the end to make it clearer.

Comment: Why are the two expressions for $Y$ equal?

Comment: @gt6989b: When that happens, you can edit your comment for up to five minutes to correct the errors.

Comment: @joriki I asked that exact question separately. They do appear to be identical however if you compute them numerically.

Comment: @joriki Thanks, could not figure out then how to correct it, now I remembered it's 2 parameters, not through a comma. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my version (up to computaitonal errors).  Information on Lambert's W function $W(z)$ can be found in (Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey, & Knuth, "On the Lambert W Function").  Begin with
\begin{equation*}
-W(-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}\,z^n
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
The radius of covergence is $e^{-1}$.  It is analytic beyond the circle 
$|z|=e^{-1}$ everywhere except the point $e^{-1}$, where it has a
quadratic branch point.  We may expand at that point:
$$
-W(-z) = 1 - \sqrt{2}(1-ez)^{1/2} + \frac{2}{3}(1-ez)
-\frac{11\sqrt{2}}{36}(1-ez)^{3/2} +\dots
$$
as $z \to e^{-1}$ from the left (that is, $z$ approaches from
inside the circle of convergence).
From (1), differentiate then multiply by $z$ to get
$\sum n^{n} z^n/n!$.  Again, differentiate then multiply by $z$ to get
$\sum n^{n+1} z^n/n!$.  The result is
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{-W(-z)}{\big(1+W(-z)\big)^3}
 =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}z^n
\tag{2}\end{equation*}
Multiply (1) and (2) to get
\begin{align*}
 h(z) &:= \frac{W(-z)^2}{\big(1+W(-z)\big)^3} =
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}\;
 \frac{(n-k)^{n-k+1}}{(n-k)!}\right)z^n
 \\ &=
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n!}
 \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k+1}\right)z^n
 =: \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n
\tag{3}\end{align*}
The singularity for $h(z)$  nearest the origin is again at $z=e^{-1}$,
and the expansion there is
\begin{align*}
 h(z) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(1-ez)^{-3/2}
 &-\frac{1}{2}(1-ez)^{-1}
 -\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}(1-ez)^{-1/2}
 \\ &
 +\frac{149}{540}
 -\frac{767}{8640\sqrt{2}}(1-ez)^{1/2} +O\big((1-ez)\big)
\end{align*}
as $z \to e^{-1}$ from the left.

Now, we use a theorem of Szegö (or Darboux?) to deduce the asymptotics
of the coefficents of power series $h(z)$.
(Szegö, *Orthogonal Polynomials*, Theorem 8.4;
quoted in Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*, 1st edition,
Theorem 5.3.2).  We have an asymptotic series, as $n \to \infty$
\begin{align*}
 c_n &\approx e^n\Bigg[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\binom{n+1/2}{n}
 -\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{n}
 -\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}\binom{n-1/2}{n}
 \\ & \qquad\qquad
 +\frac{149}{540}\binom{n-1}{n}
 -\frac{767}{8640\sqrt{2}}\binom{n-3/2}{n} +\dots
 \Bigg]&
 \\ c_n &= e^n
 \Bigg[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}n^{1/2}+
 \frac{3}{4\sqrt{\pi}}n^{-1/2}
 -\frac{7}{64\sqrt{\pi}}n^{-3/2} +O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)\right)
 -\frac{1}{2}\big(1\big)
 \\ & \qquad\qquad
 -\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}n^{-1/2}
 -\frac{1}{8\sqrt{\pi}} n^{-3/2}+O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)\right)
 +\frac{149}{540}\big(0\big)
 \\ & \qquad\qquad
 -\frac{767}{8640\sqrt{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}n^{-3/2}
 +O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)\right)
 +O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)\Bigg]
 \\ &=
 e^n\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}n^{1/2} -\frac{1}{2}
 +\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}} n^{-1/2}
 +\frac{23}{4320\sqrt{2\pi}}n^{-3/2}
 +O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)\right]
\tag{4}\end{align*}
Now from (3) we see that the required expression is $n! c_n$.
So we need the asymptotic expression
\begin{align*}
 n! &=
 e^{-n} n^n \sqrt{2\pi}\left(
 n^{1/2}+\frac{1}{12}n^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{288}n^{-3/2}
 +O\left(n^{-5/2}\right)
 \right)
\tag{5}\end{align*}
Multiply (4) and (5) to get
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k+1} = n!c_n
 \\ &\qquad =
 n^n\Bigg( n
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} n^{1/2} + \frac{1}{3}
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{24} n^{-1/2}
 +\frac{4}{135}n^{-1}
 -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{576}n^{-3/2}
 +O\left(n^{-2}\right)\Bigg)
\end{align*}

Comment: So I agree with the two most significant terms, but not the third term.  I get $1/3$ and not the predicted $1$.

Comment: This is a great answer and you are right about the $1/3$ as well (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people ).  Would you be able to apply the same type of reasoning (please) to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361452/asymptotics-of-sum-of-binomials where the current answer isn't quite right asymptotically I think.

Answer (score 4):

The upper summation bound can be lowered:
$$
   X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1} \left(n-k\right)^{n+1-k} \stackrel{k =n-m}{=} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{m} m^{m+1} (n-m)^{n-1-m}
$$
The latter representation shows that the ratio of $c_{n-k}/c_k$ is $\left(\frac{k}{n-k}\right)^2$ and is less than 1 for $2k < n$.

For a fixed $k$, and $n>k$:
$$
     \frac{1}{n^{n+1}} \binom{n}{k} k^{k-1} \left(n-k\right)^{n+1-k} = \mathrm{e}^{-k}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} \frac{n! e^{n}}{n^{n+1/2}} \frac{(n-k)^{n-k+1/2} }{(n-k)! \mathrm{e}^{n-k}} \sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n}} < \mathrm{e}^{-k}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}
$$
Indeed, asymptotically:
$$ 
   \frac{n! e^{n}}{n^{n+1/2}} \frac{(n-k)^{n-k+1/2} }{(n-k)! \mathrm{e}^{n-k}} \sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n}} = 1 - \frac{k}{2n} - \frac{k(3k+1)}{12 n^2} + \mathcal{o}(n^{-2}) < 1
$$
Therefore:
$$
  X_n < n^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \mathrm{e}^{-k}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} < n^{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-k}\frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} = n^{n+1} \left(-W\left(-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)\right) = n^{n+1}
$$
where $W(x)$ is the Lambert's $W$-function, and we used $W(-\mathrm{e}^{-1})=-1$.

[image]