# How to use generating functions to prove that $n^n=\sum\limits^{n-1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}k^k(n-k)^{n-k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Can anyone help? How can we use generating functions to prove the following identity:

$$n^n=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}k^k(n-k)^{n-k-1}$$

Comment: One question mark per sentence is sufficient. Also, use the `\binom{n}{k}` command for binomial coefficients.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347124/how-to-prove-sum-limits-k-0nn-choose-kk-1kn-k1n-k-1-nn/352204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^nx^n}{n!}$ as the exponential generating function of the left hand side.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{{n \choose k}k^k(n-k)^{n-k-1}x^n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^k}{k!}\left(\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-k)^{n-k-1}x^n}{(n-k)!}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-k)^{n-k-1}x^n}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{n-1}x^{n+k}}{n!}=-x^kW(-x)$$ where $W$ is the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Special_values), defined by $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$ with the principal branch having the series expansion $W(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}x^n}{n!}$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{{n \choose k}k^k(n-k)^{n-k-1}x^n}{n!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^k(-x^kW(-x))}{k!}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^kx^k}{k!}\right)-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^kx^k}{k!}$$

Comment: I don't get the second last step. Can you explain it?