# How to prove $ \sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \binom{k}{r}\cdot r^r \cdot (k-r)^{k-r-1} = k^k-k^{k-1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove the following identity:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \binom{k}{r}\cdot r^r \cdot (k-r)^{k-r-1} = k^k-k^{k-1}
$$
I have no idea how to tackle it because of the $r^r$. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You know about binomial expansion?

Comment: Yes, but it won't work since $r$ is in the base and in the exponent.

Comment: @user109899 I think you could look at 'Abel's binomial identity'. See this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_binomial_theorem or this post:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347124/how-to-prove-sum-limits-k-0nn-choose-kk-1kn-k1n-k-1-nn

Comment: This expression has [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) written all over it. Take $f[x]=x^x$, and use the fact that $\displaystyle{k\choose r}={k\choose k-r}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a quick combinatorial proof. Both sides of the equation answer the question

> How many ways are there to choose a rooted tree on the distinct vertices $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, and then choose one of the edges?

The right hand side is $(k-1)k^{k-1}$. We interpret $k^{k-1}$ as the number of rooted trees on $k$ vertices, while $(k-1)$ gives the choice of an edge.

Given a rooted tree on $k$ vertices, along with a distinguished edge, removing the edge leaves two disconnected trees, one which contains the root of the original tree. It follows that another way of choosing a rooted tree with a distinguished edge is to...

- Select $r$ vertices from $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, in $\binom{k}r$ ways,
- Choose a rooted tree on these $r$ vertices in $r^{r-1}$ ways,
- Choose an *unrooted* tree on the remaining $k-r$ vertices in $(k-r)^{k-r-2}$ ways, and
- Choose a vertex from the rooted tree (in $r$ ways) and a vertex from the unrooted tree (in $k-r$ ways) and join them with a distinguished edge.

Comment: Astonishingly elegant! +1

Answer (score 5):

We  can  prove this  using  the *labelled  tree
function* that is known from combinatorics.
The idea that we use a convolution is sound but we actually have to do the algebra.

This will  provide a  closed form  of  the exponential
generating function of the two terms that are involved.

We seek to show that
$$\sum_{r=1}^{k-1} {k\choose r} r^r (k-r)^{k-r-1}
= k^k - k^{k-1}.$$

Observe that when we  multiply two exponential generating functions of
the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that

$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the generating
function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

In the present case we have
$$A(z) = \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{q^q}{q!} z^q
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{q^{q-1}}{q!} z^q.$$

The species of labelled trees has the specification
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

Extracting coefficients via Lagrange inversion we have
$$Q_n
= n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} T(z) dz.$$

Put $T(z)=w$ so that $z=w/\exp(w) = w\exp(-w)$ and 
$dz = \exp(-w) - w\exp(-w) \; dw$ 
to get
$$n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+1))}{w^{n+1}} 
\times w\times (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^n} (1 - w) dw.$$

But we have 
$$n! [w^{n-1}] \exp(w n) = 
n! \times \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = n^n$$
and
$$n! [w^{n-2}] \exp(w n) = 
n! \times \frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} = n (n-1) n^{n-2} = (n-1) n^{n-1}$$
which means that $T(z)$ is the exponential generating function
of $$n^n - (n-1) n^{n-1} = n^{n-1}
\quad\text{i.e.}\quad
T(z) = \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{q^{q-1}}{q!} z^q.$$
This also follows from Cayley's theorem.

The  equality  that  we seek  to  prove  is  the convolution  the  two
exponential generating functions $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ and to verify it we
must show that
$$k! [z^k] A(z) B(z) = k^k - k^{k-1}.$$
But we have (differentiate termwise)
$$A(z) = z \frac{d}{dz} T(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad B(z) = T(z).$$

Observe that
$$z T'(z) = z \left(\exp T(z) + z \exp T(z) T'(z) \right)
= T(z) + z T(z) T'(z)$$
which implies that
$$z T'(z) = \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

It follows that
$$k! [z^k] A(z) B(z)
= k! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{T(z)^2}{1-T(z)} dz.$$
Using the same substitution as before this becomes
$$k! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(w(k+1))}{w^{k+1}} 
\times \frac{w^2}{1-w}\times (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) dw
\\ = k! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(wk)}{w^{k-1}} dw
= k! \frac{k^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}
= (k-1) k^{k-1} = k^k - k^{k-1}.$$

The *labelled tree function* recently appeared at this 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938519/).

Answer (score 1):

> This identity is a special case of *Abel's identity*, which is sometimes considered as *deep* generalisation of the binomial theorem. This formulation can be found e.g. in the classic *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* by Louis Comtet in section 3.1. The identity is stated there in the form
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x(x-kz)^{k-1}(y+kz)^{n-k}=(x+y)^{n}
> \end{align*}
>   valid for all x,y,z in a commutative ring. If we put $z=0$ we recover the binomial identity.

A rather elementary proof of OPs claim is given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823244/intuitive-ways-to-get-formula-of-binomial-like-sum/1852052#1852052)*.

> With the usual convention $0^0:=1$ you can start the summation with $r=0$ and write the formula as
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{r} r^r  (k-r)^{k-r-1} = k^k
> \end{align*}
>   Reverting the summation $r \rightarrow k-1-r$ gives
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{r+1} (k-r-1)^{k-r-1}  (r+1)^{r+1} = k^k
> \end{align*}
>   Finally shifting the index $r$ by one is precisely the identity which is proved in the *[referred answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823244/intuitive-ways-to-get-formula-of-binomial-like-sum/1852052#1852052)*.
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=1}^{k} \binom{k}{r}  r^r(k-r)^{k-r}  = k^k
> \end{align*}