# Compute the following sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}(i+1)^{i-1}(n - i + 1) ^ {n - i - 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the sum 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\cdot (i+1)^{i-1}\cdot(n - i + 1) ^ {n - i - 1},$$
but I don't know how to compute it. It's not for a homework, it's for a graph theory problem that I try to solve.

Comment: It isn't an equation, as you haven't claimed anything equals anything else. What is your actual question?

Comment: Did you evaluate the first terms ? Did you try to find a recurrence ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A089104

Comment: It's equal to $2(n+2)^{n-1}$

Comment: Yes, I found this, but I want to know how to get to this result.

Comment: @IrvinStone Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. You can [edit] your question. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up Abel's binomial theorem,
for example, here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_binomial_theorem

I find this funny because,
immediately preceding this,
I answered a question
by giving a reference to
Abel's summation formula.

This means,
of course,
that somebody will ask
about solving the quintic.

Answer (score 3):

What follows  makes no claim to  originality and is  based on material
from  [OEIS  A000272](https://oeis.org/A000272).  This computation  is
very      similar      to      the      one     at      this      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998063/).

We  can  prove this  using  the *labelled  tree
function* that is known from combinatorics.

The idea that we use a convolution is sound but we actually have to do
the algebra.

This will  provide a  closed form  of  the exponential
generating function of the two terms that are involved.

We seek to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (k+1)^{k-1} (n-k+1)^{n-k-1}
= 2 \times (n+2)^{n-1}.$$

The combinatorial class of labelled rooted trees has the specification
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

We have $n!  [z^n] T(z) = n^{n-1}$, for a proof  consult the link from
the introduction. This implies that
$$\frac{1}{z} T(z) = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-2} \frac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Observe that when we  multiply two exponential generating functions of
the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ we get that

$$ A(z) B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} 
\sum_{n\ge 0} b_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} z^n\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_k b_{n-k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n\ge 0} 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}\right)\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

i.e. the  product of  the two generating  functions is  the generating
function of $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a_k b_{n-k}.$$

In the present case we have
$$A(z) = B(z) =
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{(q+1)^{q-1}}{q!} z^q.$$

The  equality  that  we seek  to  prove  is  the convolution of the  two
exponential generating functions $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ and to verify it we
must show that
$$n! [z^n] A(z) B(z) = 2 \times (n+2)^{n-1}$$
But we have
$$A(z) = B(z) = \frac{1}{z} T(z).$$

It follows that
$$n! [z^n] A(z) B(z)
= n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{T(z)^2}{z^2} dz.$$
Using the same substitution as before (consult link) this becomes
$$n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+3))}{w^{n+3}} 
\times w^2\times (\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+2))}{w^{n+1}} (1-w) dw
\\ = n!
\left(\frac{(n+2)^n}{n!} - \frac{(n+2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)
\\ = (n+2)^n - n \times (n+2)^{n-1}
= (n+2)^{n-1} (n+2-n) = 2\times (n+2)^{n-1}.$$

The *labelled tree function* recently appeared at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938519/).