# Is it possible to write an indefinite integral of $\int \frac{1}{x+e^x} dx$ using famous special functions?

Tags: calculus

On the entrance exam of the Tokyo Institute of Technology, the problem below was asked:

> Find the integer part of a real number $\displaystyle \int^{2023}_{0} \dfrac{2}{x+e^x}dx$.

This problem asked that the entrance exam candidates use inequalities $\dfrac{2}{2e^x-1}\leq\dfrac{2}{x+e^x}\leq \dfrac{2}{e^x}$ or something similar to evaluate this value, as the indefinite integral cannot be written in elementary functions. Then a question occurred to me: Can this indefinite integral be written with some famous functions that are not elementary? Though I have no clue about this, I'm curious about this. I would appreciate it if you have any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: The integral is less than $$\int\limits_0^{2023}2e^{-x}\,dx =2(1-e^{-2023})$$ Therefore the integer part is equal $0$ or $1.$

Comment: The integral can only be calculated numerically , but to answer the question, the calculation of the integral is not necessary.

Comment: I would proceed by factoring $e^x$ out of the denominator, then rewrite the fraction using geometric series, and integrate term by term. You would likely need to use parametric differentiation to simplify the integral as I believe it would require several integration by parts. You may be able to write that resulting expression using special functions.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha knows many special functions and will give them as the results of integrals, but it can't do this one. That doesn't prove that it can't be done; it doesn't even prove that it can't be done using only special functions that Wolfram Alpha knows about. But it's a bad sign.

Comment: Don’t think this one has an antiderivative defined with typical special functions, since mathematica didn’t output anything

Comment: Wolfram Alpha uses the Risch-algorithm. If it finds no antiderivate , it can usually safely be assumed that there is none. But as said , we do not need the antiderivate anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already a few answers, but here is a simple series expansion substituting and using the [Lambert W series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700919/how-to-derive-the-lambert-w-function-series-expansion):

$$e^x+x=u\implies x=f(u)du,f(u)=u+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ne^{nu}n^{n-1}}{n!}$$

Now integrate:

$$\int\frac{dx}{e^x+x}=\int\frac{f’(u)}udx=\ln(u)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n n^n}{n!}\int\frac{e^{nu}}udu$$

Therefore the [Ei function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Ei%28x%29) appears:

$$\int\frac1{e^x+x}dx=C+\ln(e^x+x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-n)^n}{n!}\operatorname{Ei}(n(e^x+x))$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7BNIntegrate%5B1%2F%28e%5Ex%2Bx%29%2C%7Bx%2C-3.0%2C-2.0%7D%5D%2Clim%5Bln%28x%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+Ei%28n+x%29+n%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2Cx%3D-2%2Be%5E-2.0%5D-lim%5Bln%28x%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+Ei%28n+x%29+n%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D%2Cx%3D-3%2Be%5E-3.0%5D%7D). This result works for about $x<-1$

Answer (score 2):

You can't integrate with elementary functions, but you can get a very accurate estimate.

$\int \frac {2}{x+e^x} \ dx\\
\int 2e^{-x} \frac {1}{1+xe^{-x}} \ dx\\
\int 2e^{-x} \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-xe^{-x})^n \ dx\\
2\int  \sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^ne^{-(n+1)x} \ dx$

We can interchange the integral and summation when we have dominated convergence.

$2\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int  x^ne^{-(n+1)x} \ dx\\
\int  x^ne^{-(n+1)x} \ dx = \frac {n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}e^{-(n+1)x}P(x)$

Where $P(x)$ is a polynomial.

Evaluating at $x = 2023$ any polynomial will be trivial compared to the exponential factor that preceeds it.

$\int_0^{2023}  x^ne^{-(n+1)x} \ dx$ very nearly equals $\int_0^{\infty}  x^ne^{-(n+1)x} \ dx = \frac {n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$

In a small number of terms $(n+1)^{n+1} \gg n!$

$2(1 - \frac 1{4} + \frac {2}{27} - \frac {6}{256} + \cdots)\approx 1.613$
Which matches what we find from numerical integration.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint%5B0to+2023%5D+++2%2F%28x+%2B+e%5Ex%29+dx

Answer (score -4):

No, there is no function. But it should be smaller than $\int_0^{2023}\frac{2}{e^x}~dx$ and since this is less than $1$ the answer is $0$.

Comment: They're not asking for an answer to the original question. They're asking about evaluating the antiderivative using special functions.

Comment: They are asking for some known function and the answer was there is none.

Comment: @trula except you merely assert it does not exist, without reference or proof.

Comment: And it is smaller than $2/e^x,$ not $1/e^x.$