# The Maclaurin expansion of the Lambert function $y=y(x)$ defined as $y(x)\cdot e^{y(x)}=x, y(0)=0.$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Maclaurin expansion of the Lambert function $y=y(x)$ defined as $$y(x)\cdot e^{y(x)}=x, y(0)=0.$$

I find it easier to think of the Lambert function as the solution of the equation $ye^y=x$. So $y=y(x)$.

Maybe it's more clear if we denote it $w(x)$. So the solution of $ye^y=x$ is $y=w(x)$. It gives us $y$ in terms of $x$.

We know that $ye^y=x$. Let's differentiate both sides to get $$y'e^y+yy'e^y=1\\e^yy'(1+y)=1\\y'=\dfrac{y}{x(1+y)}$$

How do I find the next derivatives?

A Maclaurin series is a Taylor series expansion of a function about $0$, so it will be something like this: $$y(0)+\dfrac{y'(0)}{1!}x+\dfrac{y''(0)}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{y'''(0)}{3!}x^3+\dots$$

Okay but isn't $y'(0)$ undefined as we plug $x=0$ which is in the denominator?

THIS DOES NOT ANSWER MY QUESTION: [How to derive the Lambert W function series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700919/how-to-derive-the-lambert-w-function-series-expansion). Thank you!

Comment: "Okay but isn't $y′(0)$ undefined as we plug $x=0$ which is in the denominator?" Notice that $\frac{y}{x}=e^y$, hence $y'(0)=\frac{e^{y(0)}}{1+y(0)}=\frac{e^0}{1+0}=1.$

Comment: @Gonçalo, thank you! May you help me with finding the next derivatives?

Comment: And why that post does not answer your question?

Comment: @Gonçalo, as Math Student pointed out it really doesn't make the point clear for me as well. How would I find the second derivative for example?

Comment: This derivation can be done with [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). More in the following [article](https://habr.com/ru/articles/745880/)

Comment: Differentiate the equation $e^yy'(1+y)=1$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: @EgorIvanov, I'm not familiar with that theorem.

Comment: @Gonçalo in terms of y, right?

Comment: @SAQ Okay, check it on Wiki. Looks logical from even from the outside view.

Comment: @SAQ Lagrange inversion is mentioned in the question you linked, but you said it did not answer your question. What method are you looking for to find the series expansion?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash, well as we would for $e^x$ for example. Just finding the derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

*From my old cookbook.*

The $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of  $W_0(x)$ is  given  by
$$\frac {d^n\,W_0(x)}{dx^n}=\frac{e^{-n W_0(x)}\,P_n\big(W_0(x)\big)}{ \big(1+W_0(x)\big)^{2n-1}}$$ where the very first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(w) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & -(w+2) \\
 3 & 2 w^2+8 w+9 \\
 4 & -(6 w^3+36 w^2+79 w+64) \\
 5 & 24 w^4+192 w^3+622 w^2+974 w+625 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

These polynomials satisfy the recurrence relation
$$P_{n+1}(w)=-\big(n (w + 3) - 1\big)P_{n}(w)+(1+w)P'_{n}(w)$$

Comment: How did you find the recurrence relation?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash. May I confess that I do not remember ? As I wrote, it was in my old cookbook. Problem of age, for sure. Cheers :-)